# Ionic angular: opening links in (external) mobile browser

Tags: android, ionic-framework, browser

I do not want links to open inside my Ionic app, so I'm trying to get the links to open in the mobile browser.
The first example here is working fine. When the URL is inside of the "window.open" command, then the external browser is launched as expected.

```
            <p class="descriptive-class">
               <a ng-href="" onclick="window.open('https://stackoverflow.com', '_system', 'location=yes')">
                  <img src="assets/img/awesome_picture.png" alt="blablabla">
               </a>
            </p>
```

The problem lays with this part, where I want to feed a parameter for the URL to the code. I cannot set it directly inside "window.open()", so I have to move it to 'ng-href' and then refer to it via 'this.href'.

Android does not seem to understand this correctly. It shows me the "Complete action using" dialog on Android, and then presents HTML document handler applications. It does not understand the browser link.

How can this be corrected best?

```
            <p class="descriptive-class">
               <a href="#" ng-href="item.webURL" onclick="window.open(this.href, '_system', 'location=yes')">
                  {{ item.webURL }}
               </a>
           </p>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this case, the easiest way is to install the **In App Browser** plugin.

It opens an URL with the installed browser of the device. First add and install the plugin:

```
*$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser*
*$ npm install --save @ionic-native/in-app-browser*
```

Add it to your **app.module.ts**

```
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';
```

And add it to your **providers**:

```
@NgModule({
  ...

  providers: [
    ...
    InAppBrowser
    ...
  ]
  ...
})
```

Then add on the **relevant page**:

```
constructor(private iab: InAppBrowser) { }

openBrowser(){
    this.iab.create('https://ionicframework.com/');
}
```

Call `openBrowser()` in your (click) method and you're set!

*See also: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser/*

Comment: This is indeed a much easier solution, and much cleaner in the end. I was misguided by the plugin's name "in-app browser", but it works also to launch the external browser!  The documentation was a bit unclear in the given example, so the code to call the link in external browser, looks like this: `openExternalBrowser(link) {
    this.iab.create(link, '_system'); }`

Comment: Thank @Gerben. I tried this and it's working fine but my requirement is a little different I don't want a button to open a link. I directly want a link to open in the app I've created but it should not redirect to the browser in the phone like in chrome.

Answer (score 3):

As of Feb 2020, this is what works in Ionic 4 & Ionic 5:

1) Install [In App Browser plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser). Don't worry, it will open the links externally as you want it. Run the following commands in your project root:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
npm install @ionic-native/in-app-browser
```

2) In **`app.module.ts`** file, add the following code:

**Add the import as shown below:**

`import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx';`

**Add support for `InAppBrowser` by adding it to the `providers` array as shown below:**

```
 providers: [
        StatusBar,
        SplashScreen,
        InAppBrowser, // ---> Add it here
        {provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy}
    ],
```

3) In your desired **component TS file** or **page TS file** (***example: support.page.ts)***, add the following code:

**Add the import as shown below:**

`import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx';`

**Add the code in constructor as shown below:**

```
constructor(private iab: InAppBrowser) {}
```

**Add a method that opens the link to your desired webpage as shown below:**

```
openPage(){
        this.iab.create('https://stackoverflow.com/'); // --> Change URL here
}
```

**Add click event to your hyperlink as shown below:**

```
<a href="#" (click)="openPage()">{{ item.webURL }}</a>
```

**Result:**

Now when you click on the Hyperlink, that should open your desired URL.

**NOTE:**

If you do not want to hardcode the URL and would rather want to open URLs dynamically, then you can **use the following in your HTML page**:

```
<a href="#" (click)="openAnyPage(item.webURL)">{{ item.webURL }}</a>
```

**Add the following in your TS file:**

```
openAnyPage(url){
        this.iab.create(url);
}
```

**Result:**

Now when you click on any Hyperlink, that should open your desired URL, without the need to hardcode them anywhere.

Comment: @denver what if I want only a website to be open in my app and not on a click directly and it should not open in an external browser

Comment: Shouldn't it be openAnyPage(url){
        this.iab.create(url, '_system');
}

Answer (score 1):

An update to @Gerben den Boer's answer:

You will run into errors like the following with the import as it is listed.

```
[ng] ERROR in src/app/components/app-component/app.module.ts(44,5): error TS2322: Type 'InAppBrowserOriginal' is not assignable to type 'Provider'.
[ng]   Type 'InAppBrowserOriginal' is not assignable to type 'ClassProvider'.
[ng]     Property 'provide' is missing in type 'InAppBrowserOriginal'.
```

To resolve this use the following import:

```
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx';
```

See: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/issues/2899

Answer (score 0):

Further to @Devner's excellent answer, for a 2021+ (Ionic5) release,
You should do all of the above, but 2 things needed to change for me.

I had multiple variables to pass to it, that suggestion didn't work, but I did overcome the problem with the following:

```
<a href="#" (click)="openAnyPage(country_website,wp_id)">Open original article.</a>
```

Also, please note the following that was left off, according to the [Cordova Documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser)...

A target should be included:
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, target, options);
ref: Reference to the InAppBrowser window when the target is set to '_blank'. (InAppBrowser)

url: The URL to load (String). Call encodeURI() on this if the URL contains Unicode characters.

target: The target in which to load the URL, an optional parameter that defaults to _self. (String)

**_system: Opens in the system's web browser.**

Therefore, the following code brings it altogether:

```
openAnyPage(url, wp_id)
  {
    this.iab.create(url+"index.php?page_id="+wp_id, '_system');
  }
```